# How to set value in SharedPreferences as standard?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i know how to set and get a value in shared preferences:

But this works only while the app is started.

I wonder how i can set some values as standard so they are set even by starting the app the first time. So not the code is setting them, instead its just like writing something in strings.xml.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where is your SDK ROOT?  check the samples on shared Prefs....

$SDK_HOME/samples/$platform/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/preference/DefaultValues.java

is the sample u want.

example in  Main_Activity.onCreate():

```
 PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.your-defaults, false); 

... 

 PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("default_user_oid", "default").equalsIgnoreCase("default")
```

Comment: so this sets the default values every time, the app is started, but doesn't overwrite the values if they had been changed?

Comment: No. on new install / uninstall the prefs get wiped or installed. When you update SharedPrefs in the app, those will PERSIST until such time as you uninstall.... Think about it . Its app data.